# OOP PHP architecture

Tags: php, oop, architecture

Sorry if my question is wishy-washy.

I'm new to OOP. What I'm wondering is how "object orientated" should I go with my new project. Although I'm not up on all the tech lingo I think I have a reasonable understanding of classes/objects as data types. What is preventing me from launching right into it is the uncertainty about the "right" architecture.

For example, right now I have a standard class that can be instantiated as an object holding the database handle and has methods for getRow, getRows, insertRow, updateRow to which queries and parameters are sent and that all works.

It just doesn't seem correct that I'm just creating the $db object in the top of a page and then handing that to every object that needs it.

The system I'm building has distinct page types, e.g blog pages, product pages, checkout, etc. I'm using apache rewrites to send all requests to a single page on which I will switch out the code that is executed.

Would it seem correct to instantiate an object for each type.

```
if($pageType = "blog-post"){
  $page = new BlogPost($db);
}
else if($pageType = "product-listings"){
  $page = new ProductListing($db);
}

$page->SendToView();
```

If I ensure that the $page object always has a SendToView method that worries about how the page is displayed.

Are there more than one implementations of the MVC pattern? I assumed MVC is what I need but when I looked for tutorials they seem completely different but all refer to themselves as MVC.

Comment: You're using assignments `=` rather than comparisons `==`. So your code as posted, is failing, unless that's pseudo code.

Comment: yes there are a lot of mvc variations out there

Comment: OOP and MVC are two different things.  Use a simple framework like CodeIgniter to experiment with MVC.

Comment: @Bimal Codeigniters has **nothing** to do with MVC.

Comment: @tereško not sure what you are pointing at. But codeigniter framework has MVC and is also in PHP.

Comment: @Bimal since you are clueless, let me illuminate this for you. MVC is an architectural pattern, that your application code (well .. not your, but of some other people) implements. MVC is not something, that a framework can have or not have. But if we are talking about CodeIgniter in particular, I can tell you what it does have: bad programming practices, anti-patterns, global state and extremely ignorant community.

Comment: @teresko You have illuminated me with some good points which I have yet to validate. I am neither defending nor promoting codeigniter.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. In the end I created my own little framework that just looks up the required controller from the database based on the url.